# What can be my problem with my client api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a simple full stack application with a self made API that has to store transactions, it receives a description of the transaction, the amount (negative or positive), the date the transaction was made and a transaction type (income, expense). The API works just fine, I can make GET, POST and DELETE requests to it with Postman, my problem seems to be at the front end and I can't find a way to solve it, the GET request works but when I want to make a POST request the data I send from my form gets to the API with null values. I tried making the request with Axios and using fetch, but none of them solved the issue. I hope somebody can give me a hand with it

This is my code on my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const apiRouter = require("./routes/api");

const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

require("./db");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("response");
});

app.use("/api", apiRouter);

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Está vivo!");
});
```

This is from my api.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const middleWares = require("./middlewares");
const apiTransactionsRouter = require("./api/transactions");
const apiUsersRouter = require("./api/users");

router.use("/transactions", /*middleWares.checkToken,*/ apiTransactionsRouter);
router.use("/users", apiUsersRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

And this is from the app.js (there might be some useless lines, I'm aware of it, but I'm trying to finish the app to clear the file a bit, so forgive me for that)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter, ModalHeader } from "reactstrap";





class App extends Component {
  //state
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      transactions: [],
      isLoading: false,
      isError: false,
      createModal: false,
      form: {
        id: "",
        concepto: "",
        monto: "",
        fecha: "",
        tipo: "",
      },
    };
  }

  //get petition
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/transactions/");

    //check the answer
    if (resp.ok) {
      const transactions = await resp.json();
      /*console.log(transactions);*/
      this.setState({ transactions, isLoading: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isError: true, isLoading: false });
    }
  }

  //post petition with fetch
  async postPetition() {
    try {
      let result = fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/transactions/", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          //Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          form: {
            concepto: this.state.form.concepto,
            monto: this.state.form.monto,
            fecha: this.state.form.fecha,
            tipo: this.state.form.tipo,
          },
        }),
      });
      this.componentDidMount();
      this.createModal();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  //post petition with axios
  /*postPetition = async () => {
    delete this.state.form.id;
    await axios
      .post(url, this.state.form)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);
        this.createModal();
        this.componentDidMount();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };*/

  //render table functions
  renderTableHeader = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.state.transactions[0]).map((attribute) => (
      <th key={attribute}>{attribute.toUpperCase()}</th>
    ));
  };

  renderTableRows = () => {
    return this.state.transactions.map((transaction) => {
      return (
        <tr key={transaction.id}>
          <td>{transaction.id}</td>
          <td>{transaction.description}</td>
          <td>{transaction.amount}</td>
          <td>{transaction.date}</td>
          <td>{transaction.transactionType}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => this.selectTransaction(transaction)}
            >
              Editar
            </button>
            {"  "}
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  //create transaction
  createModal = () => {
    this.setState({ createModal: !this.state.createModal });
  };

  //select transaction
  selectTransaction = (transaction) => {
    this.setState({
      modalType: "update",
      form: {
        id: transaction.id,
        concepto: transaction.description,
        monto: transaction.amount,
        fecha: transaction.date,
        tipo: transaction.transactionType,
      },
    });
  };

  //handle change function
  handleChange = async (e) => {
    e.persist();
    await this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
    console.log(this.state.form);
  };

  //App
  render() {
    const { form } = this.state;

    const { transactions, isLoading, isError } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Cargando...</div>;
    }

    if (isError) {
      return <div>Error...</div>;
    }

    return transactions.length > 0 ? (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Tu saldo es de:</h1> <br />
          <p>$0</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.createModal()}>
          Nueva operación
        </button>
        <br /> <br />
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Concepto</th>
              <th>Monto</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Tipo</th>
              <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.renderTableRows()}</tbody>
        </table>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.createModal}>
          <ModalHeader style={{ display: "block" }}>
            <span style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => this.createModal()}>
              x
            </span>
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="id">ID</label>
              <input
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                name="id"
                readOnly
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={form ? form.id : this.state.transactions.length + 1}
              />
              <br />

              <label htmlFor="description">Concepto</label>
              <br />
              <input
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                name="concepto"
                id="concepto"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={form ? form.concepto : ""}
                placeholder="Compra, venta, etc..."
              />
              <br />

              <label htmlFor="amount">Monto</label>
              <br />
              <input
                className="form-group"
                type="text"
                name="monto"
                id="monto"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={form ? form.monto : ""}
                placeholder="Monto"
              />
              <br />

              <label htmlFor="date">Fecha</label>
              <br />
              <input
                className="form-group"
                type="date"
                name="fecha"
                id="fecha"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={form ? form.fecha : ""}
              />
              <br />

              <label htmlFor="transactionType">Tipo de operación</label>
              <br />
              <input
                className="form-group"
                type="text"
                name="tipo"
                id="tipo"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={form ? form.tipo : ""}
                placeholder="Ingreso o egreso..."
              />
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <button
              className="btn btn-success"
              onClick={() => this.postPetition()}
            >
              Crear
            </button>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => this.createModal()}
            >
              Cancelar
            </button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>No hay información para mostrar...</div>
    );
  }
}
/*{this.renderTableHeader()}*/

export default App;
```

Comment: You are sending `POST` in JSON format?

Comment: Nono, I changed it to x-www-form-url-encoded, at first it looked like the problem was because I was sending the data in json format, but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sending JSON, set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. And you have to `await` the result of the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) call since it returns a promise.

```js
const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/transactions/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    form: {
      concepto: this.state.form.concepto,
      monto: this.state.form.monto,
      fecha: this.state.form.fecha,
      tipo: this.state.form.tipo,
    },
  }),
})
```

You can then access the values in the backend via `req.body.form`.

```js
const { concepto, monto, fecha, tipo } = req.body.form
```

Comment: Oooh I got it, I forgot to add the await to fetch, I appreciate it man! I'll try those changes and I'll update the question